# Deploy multiple SSR apps under the same domain in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

I have an AWS application that has been rebuilt from Angular to React/Next, and am having a considerably difficult time figuring out how to deploy it.

The domain is comprised of four separate applications, each with their own repository:

- [domain].com (next.js, ssr)
- *.[domain].com (next.js, ssr)
- admin.[domain].com (react, non-ssr)
- api.[domain].com (node.js, express)

The admin subdomain runs in an S3 website bucket behind a cloudfront distribution I have an A record pointing to it in Route 53. The api subdomain is running on an EC2 instance also with an A record pointing to it.

The problem arises when I try to deploy both SSR apps together, which need to be running under AWS Amplify Hosting. I've created an app in Amplify for the [domain] I am using, but Amplify does not permit one application running under [domain].com and an entirely separate app running under *.[domain].com. The best it can do (and Vercel operates similarly) is have [domain].com running under one branch, and *.[domain].com running under a different branch.

I get that the purpose for that is different staging/testing environments for one application, but someone somewhere had to conceive that an SSR website should permit multiple applications running on separate domains. I can again just create a static site in S3 and abandon SSR for one of the apps, but that's poor design choice based on arbitrary configuration restrictions. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to handle? AWS wants 30 bucks a month to just answer a question (lol no).